# How to change background img with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

How to change background img with jquery by clicking on button?

My code does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#go").click(function() {
        $('body').css("background-image", "url(blue_bg.jpg)");  
    };
});
```

Comment: Before you click which background image is present?

Comment: Is url(blue_bg.jpg) valid and actually finds an image? You might put some path as well.

Comment: I suggest getting web developer tools for which ever browser you develop in, they will highlight any JS errors like this & can help suggest a fix. For example Firebug for Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try fixing like this and see if works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#go").click(function() {
      $('body').css("background-image", "url(blue_bg.jpg)");  
   }); // you forgot to close the click event
});
```